# Force relative URI in location header using ResponseBuilder

Tags: java

I'm using the ResponseBuilder class to send a redirect response using

```
responseBuilder.header("Location", "/foo");
```

My problem is that the URI resolves to an absolute URI. According to the documentation:

*If a relative URI is supplied it will be converted into an absolute URI by resolving it relative to the base URI of the application (see UriInfo.getBaseUri()). If null any existing value for location will be removed.*

Because my service runs behind a reverse proxy, the hostname of the location value gets wrong. Is there any way I can force a relative URI when returning the location header?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Host` to specify the original client or host behind a load-balancer or a reverse proxy.

> Host names and ports of reverse proxies (load balancers, CDNs) may differ from the origin server handling the request, in that case the X-Forwarded-Host header is useful to determine which Host was originally used.

from [Mozilla HTTP Headers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host).